# how do i get mysql connections to close when the ajax request is aborted?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, cakephp

I'm using cakephp and jquery, and ajax requests to get mysql data when a new company is selected. When the user selects a new company before the old company is finished loading, it aborts the request and makes a new one. The problem is that it leaves the mysql connection open (for a long time, maybe an hour). I'm using the non-persistent version of mysql connect. When a user holds the down-arrow key to scroll through companies in a multiple select, it opens hundreds of connections within a few seconds, and then everything has 'too many connections' errors.

Here is my javascript for when the company is changed

```
if ($.companiesDivXHR) {$.companiesDivXHR.abort(); }
$.companiesDivXHR = $.ajax({
    url:"/companies/details",
    success:function(html) {
        $("companiesDiv").html(html);
    }
});
```

Another example might help: I have a similar situation when I have an ajax request every 10 seconds, and it aborts if not already finished. The when the requested page takes 30 seconds or so to be delivered, it is aborted every time before it can be displayed (since 30>10), and again, a mysql connection is left open. When the ajax requested page is loaded by itself, there are no problems, and the connection closes as it should. So, the effect is much slower, but with 1 user, over the course of 20 minutes, it again causes the 'too many connections' error (if max connections is set to 100).

Comment: Umm. Slightly unrelated to your question, but why are you making a request to a server for something that could potentially happen hundreds of times a minute for any given user? Why not cache this data on the server side using something like memcache or even prefetch this data when presenting the user with said list of companies? There are a lot of smart ways to prevent a GUI page from hammering your server with requests.

Comment: Good point. I will look into caching or something for the first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing [PHP  ignore_user_abort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php), it looks like the reason connections weren't closing for me was that ignore_user_abort was set to false, which is the default. When set to true, the PHP script continues executing after either an ajax `.abort()`, or when pressing the escape key in the middle of execution. 
I tested this by going to the page that was being loaded by the ajax request, and pressing f5 followed by escape continuously. Each time I aborted from the browser, another connection was left open (seen using mytop on Ubuntu), and stayed open in 'sleep' mode until whatever timeout was reached (somewhere between 10 and 60 minutes maybe? not sure). When I switched `ignore_user_abort` on, I did the same thing, but each connection only stayed open for 30 seconds, which is how long the page itself takes to load.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you considered implementing a "delay" so that a request isn't made until an option is selected for a set amount of time (e.g. 1 second)?
2. Under a non-persistent environment, once a request is made to your PHP script, the PHP script connects to MySQL, does its business, and the MySQL connection is closed automatically at the end of script execution.
   Keeping that in mind, calling `.abort()` client-side does not halt the PHP script's execution, meaning it doesn't halt the closing of the MySQL connection. It simply stops the browser from waiting & receiving anything from the PHP script.  Your PHP script still has to finish executing on its own for the MySQL connection it's using to be closed.

There are a couple things that come to mind that could potentially be causing your issue:

1. You have persistent MySQL connections enabled *somewhere*.  I'm not familiar enough with CakePHP to tell you where to look.
2. Your PHP script fails to end properly, in which case you would be waiting for PHP's script timeout to take effect, and during that time the MySQL connection is left open, potentially leading to a "too many connections" problem.
3. Your MySQL server is not set up to handle that many requests over such a short period of time (unlikely, but possible).  If this is the case, your only option is to alleviate the number of requests, (e.g. implementing the delay, mentioned above)

Comment: I don't think persistent is enabled anywhere, the debug messages specifically point to the mysql connect where persistent is false. I am adding another example to my question.

Comment: Is response to "Keeping that in mind, calling .abort() client-side does not halt the PHP script's execution", from what I've been reading today, that is only accurate if ignore_user_abort is set to true.